# Conditioned index in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I've been going through an online tutorial

```
from sklearn.decomposition import  * 
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

digits=datasets.load_digits()

randomized_pca = PCA(n_components=2,svd_solver='randomized')

# a numpy array with shape= (1800,2)  
reduced_data_rpca = randomized_pca.fit_transform(digits.data)

# make a scatter plot

colors = ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow', 'pink', 'red', 'lime', 'cyan', 
'orange', 'gray']

start=time.time()

#   Time Taken for this loop = 9.5 seconds

# for i in range(len(reduced_data_rpca)):
#         x = reduced_data_rpca[i][0]
#         y = reduced_data_rpca[i][1]
#         plt.scatter(x,y,c=colors[digits.target[i]])

# Alternative way  TimeTaken = 0.2 sec

# plots all the points (x,y) with color[i] in ith iteration

for i in range(len(colors)):
    """assigns all the elements (accordingly to x and y)  whose label(0-9) equals the variable i (am I 
    correct ? does this mean it iterates the whole again to check for the 
    equality?) """
    x = reduced_data_rpca[:, 0][digits.target == i]  
    y = reduced_data_rpca[:, 1][digits.target == i]
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors[i])

end=time.time()

print("Time taken",end-start," Secs")
```

My question is although both commented and non-commented loops performs same operation I cannot understand how the second loop is working and why it is performing better than the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop (commented out) loops over a 1800-element array. The second one uses the indexing methods of numpy for the "inner loop" and only has to a regular `for` loop through your 10 colors. Numpy arrays are faster than regular lists and loops.

But what does `digits.target == i` do? It seems to me like it is not picking out a boolean array from `reduced_data_rpca` but doing a comparison between a dictionary and the array index over and over. Isn't the result of that comparison always `False`?

Also see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: actually `digits.target` (these are the class labels of numbers in `reduced_data_rpca`) contains 1800 values (ranged 0-9) and `reduced_data_rpca` contains 2 columns and what I am thinking  is that, it loops over this array and verifies the equality of corresponding `digits.target` value with the variable `i`. Am I being wrong?

Comment: You are right I think! Makes sense once I tried it out.